# How to access stored procedure made on Visual Studio 2015 c# from another Pc

Tags: c#

I made stored procedures on my PC using the server explorer on Visual Studio 2015

When I transferred my Project and my database file to my friend's PC the stored procedures on the server explorer are already gone

Comment: Take a look at the connection string

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm a bit new to this and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but may I ask how can I do that?

Comment: stored procedures are stored at SQL server, so first thing to check: How do you transfer your database?